# SQL select with hierarchy for default values

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have a table in the following format:

```
+---+---+--------+
| u | i | value  |   
+---+---+--------+
| 0 | 1 | Value1 |
| 0 | 2 | Value2 |
| 0 | 3 | Value3 |
| 8 | 2 | Value4 |
| 9 | 2 | Value5 |
| 9 | 3 | Value6 |
+---+---+--------+
```

My goal is to do a select that selects values from that user (u) for each id (i) if it exists, if not fall back to the value associated with 0.  A few examples:

User ID 7 (Only default values)

```
Value1
Value2
Value3
```

User Id 8 (2 default values, 1 unique)

```
Value1
Value4
Value3
```

User Id 9 (1 default values, 2 unique)

```
Value1
Value5
Value6
```

Is this possible in a single mySQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE( usr.value, def.value ) AS value
FROM your_table def
LEFT JOIN your_table usr ON ( usr.i = def.i AND usr.u = your_user )
WHERE def.u = 0
```

This selects all records where `u=0` and left joins the records of your requested user.

If they exist, take the value from there, else take the default value (Using [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)).

Note that this will only return records where a default (`u=0`) exists.

Comment: Glad I could help. With MySQL you could also use `IFNULL`, but `COALESCE` is the standard and should work with all kind of DBs.